# How to allow a maxium of 3 else loops, after which it should run another function?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm currently going through "Learn Python The Hard Way". I'm doing exercise 36, which asked to create my own simple text based game.

Unfortunately I've ran into a problem. What I'm trying to do, is basically make the function allow a maximum of 3 times of repeated use of 'else', after which it should run 'dead()' function.

I understand that using 'while', it will loop 'else' forever. I tried creating a 'for'-loop which should build a list and after number 3 it should run 'dead()', but that didn't really work. I tried positioning it before and after 'while', but that failed as well.

```
def genie():

print "Suddenly a genie appears!"
print "The genie says that it will grant 3 of your wishes. "
print "Do you want to wish something, or leave him?"

while True:
    next = raw_input("> ")


    if next == "wish":
        print "You want your 3 wishes granted. "
        wishes()

    elif next == "leave":
        print "The genie gets angry at you for wasting its time! "
        print "You suddenly appear in a huge room with a dragon in it. "
        dragon_room()

    else:
        print "The genie doesn't understand your muttering."

        i = 0
        angry = []

        for i in angry:
            print "The genie has got a little bit annoyed."
            i = i + 1
            angry.append(i)


            if i == 3:
                dead("The genie got angry and killed you!")
            else:
                exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
for i in range(3):
    next = raw_input("> ")
    if next == "wish":
        ...
        wishes()
        break
    elif next == "leave":
        ...
        dragon_room()
        break
    print "The genie doesn't understand your muttering."
    if i:
        print "The genie has got a little bit annoyed."
else:
    dead("The genie got angry and killed you.")
exit()
```

The `else` on a `for` (or `while`) loop only runs if the loop doesn't `break` early.

Answer (score 1):

You should place a count variable outside the while loop, and increase it by 1 when "The genie not understand".

```
print "Suddenly a genie appears!"
print "The genie says that it will grant 3 of your wishes. "
print "Do you want to wish something, or leave him?"

count = 0
while True:
    next = raw_input("> ")
    if next == "wish":
        print "You want your 3 wishes granted. "
        wishes()

    elif next == "leave":
        print "The genie gets angry at you for wasting its time! "
        print "You suddenly appear in a huge room with a dragon in it. "
        dragon_room()

    else:
        print "The genie doesn't understand your muttering."
        if count == 3:
            dead("The genie got angry and killed you!")
        else:
            print "The genie has got a little bit annoyed."
            count += 1
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation. Also, note that you are still inside the `while` loop after the program returns from e.g. `dragon_room`.